# Passing Long parameter to a method having signature findResults(String prop, Object val) converts to Integer data type

Tags: java

I have a method defined like this:

```
findResults(String prop, Object val) {
    if(val instanceof String)
        //process String stuff
    else if(val instanceof Long)
        //process Long stuff
    else
        //process other stuff
}
```

When I pass a Long parameter to above method

```
findResults(query, 5L);
```

it is converted to Integer data type and the last else condition is executed.
Even passing parameter as `Long.parseLong("5")` doesn't work.
How can I pass the Long value as a parameter in java?

UPDATE:
Error details:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [5] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
....
```

Comment: How about `finResults("key", new Long(5))`?

Comment: It work fine with me https://www.ideone.com/rJT7LG

Comment: `5L` is a literal for `long` primitive. Your method `findResults()` expects an `Object` and not a primitive. Since Java 5 introduced _autoboxing_, the primitive should be automatically converted to a `Long` object and as others have pointed out, this is what happens. So are you using a JDK version lower than 5? Or is the code you posted not the actual code that is causing you problems?

Comment: You are mistaken. Evidence please.

Comment: Note that `Long.parseLong("5")` still gives you a long *primitive*. If you want a `Long`, you are supposed to use `Long.valueOf("5")`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what goes wrong:

The following code prints "Long", as expected!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findResults("String", 5L);
}

static void findResults(String prop, Object val) {
    if(val instanceof String)
        System.out.println("String");
    else if(val instanceof Long)
        System.out.println("Long");
    else
        System.out.println("Other");
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't have answered. Questions that are not reproducible are off-topic - you are supposed to close with the appropriate reason.

Comment: Can't understand why down-vote? Well the problem still exists for me. Here is the error displayed on console: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [5] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]` Actual code is too lengthy to post here, having multiple method calls in between. This method belongs to a GenericJpaDAO class which i have written to generalize and execute any kind of JPQL. Will come back once I debug it thoroughly.